# HTML body is not at the top of the page even with margin set to 0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a Ruby on Rails app and I can't get the body at the top of the page. Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

I have no clue why this is happening as I've set all the properties correctly. [Here is the source of the entire application.](https://github.com/WeeklyApps/blog)  My view:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="posts">
    <% @posts.each do|post| %>
    <div id="post">
      <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
      <%= simple_format post.body %>
      <small>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </small>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
</div>
```

My CSS (the commented out CSS is the hack I wrote to fix the issue by changing the positioning of the header-wrap and wrapper elements):

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require twitter/bootstrap
 */
 html, body, {
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    background-color:#cccccc;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header-wrap {
    background-color: #424242;
/*  position: absolute;*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 588px;
}

#wrapper {
/*  position: relative;
  top: 100px;*/
    padding: 0 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 588px;
}

#posts {
}

#notice {
  color: green;
}

.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}

#error_explanation {
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #c00;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: square;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 16):

Please check your header tag. run your code removing `<h1>Blog</h1>`.

and add

```
h1{
     margin: 0;
  }
```

but keep `<h1>Blog</h1>`.

**EDITED**

make `#header-wrap{ position:absolute;}` this is because your `#header` is inside `#header-wrap` and remove

```
h1{
         margin: 0;
      }
```

Comment: Holy cow that was the culprit. Thank you! What is causing that?

Comment: h1 has -webkit-margin-top set to 0.67 by default. You don't have to remove it just set margin: 0 on it.

Comment: Leaving the h1 tag and adding h1 {margin: 0;} to the CSS didn't fix it.

Comment: yeh... i made an edit to my answer. now if you find its correct then mark it as correct answer. thank you.

Comment: That didn't fix it but the header is definitely responsible because removing the tag fixes the issue. I'm not sure why manually setting the h1 margin to 0 isn't fixing it either.

Comment: @Robert check my edited answer. here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kW9Cj/) for the same

Comment: That's exactly what I had originally but commented out. I had position: absolute on the header-wrap and then position: relative and a huge top margin to the content wrapper because it puts the content behind the header when you do that. That also doesn't fix the problem that header tags seem to be offsetting my margins because the page renders fine when I take out the heading tag. I'm wondering if maybe bootstrap is doing something weird.

Edit: Nope. Just removed bootstrap and it's still doing it. Somewhere I have something occurring that is screwing with my headings.

Comment: `#wrapper {
 position: relative;
}` will make your wrapper text to be seen below header.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in my original post and it's a hack and messy. I'd rather find out what's messing with my header tags and fix the problem than write CSS around it. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid more problems with CSS in the future, add this "Reset CSS" to the top of your stylesheet.
[Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: That didn't fix it. For some reason even using the Reset CSS to put the margin: 0 on the h1 element isn't fixing the problem. I have no clue where it's being set if the Reset CSS isn't overriding it either but removing the header tag fixes the spacing so it's clearly something with the header.

Comment: Try `h1{ padding:0; margin:0; line-height:100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

add `*{margin:0}` body will then start from 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the body had two alert paragraphs in it.

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Changed the p's to sections.